# WPF modal dialog on touch screen

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, touch

I am using a custom modal dialog in a WPF application, that will run on a touch device (Windows 10). I am using the MVVM pattern.

My problem:

I experience different touch behavior depending on from where the dialog is opened. If it is opened from, for example, a button event handler or via button command binding, everything works fine. Then dialog buttons (typically "OK" and "Cancel") closes the dialog on first touch. But when the dialog is opened from code (not driven by button event or button command binding), the dialog buttons does *not* respond on the first touch. I then need to touch somewhere in the dialog before touching the button. It is kind of annoying.

I have a view model with an ExitCommand implemented that opens the dialog. Some XAML examples:

This works fine:

```
<Button Content="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
```

This does not work satisfactory:

```
<Label Content="Exit">
    <Label.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
    </Label.InputBindings>
</Label>
```

And as mentioned, opening the dialog from code without any user action, does not work either.

Clues, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this solution will solve your problem but try this please:

xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

```
    <Label Content="Exit">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <!-- MouseDown trigger for touch down too. -->
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"
                                       x:Name="exitCommandMouse" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Label>
```

I use a similar solution with grid (instead label) and its works perfectly with touch screen on win 8.1.